# find and replace multiple values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have around 1000 excel files in a folder, I want to replace multiple values in all files from a folder. The reference sheet for find and replace is in seperate excel file with around 500 find and replace words in excel. Reference sheet consists of 2 columns Find & Replace in column A and B in sheet1. How can I replace multiple values from a multiple files using vba.

Comment: The approach I would take is: 1) Add all the required VBA code in the Reference file. 2) Iterate though all the files in a folder by opening and closing them one by one. 3) Inside the previous iteration loop place another loop that will go through all the values that need to be replaced. 4) Finally, add a function inside the above loops to search and replace all matches in the currently open file. Let me know if you need some code examples.

Comment: @Sergiy Savelyev Thank you for your reply. I am a newbie to vba so it would be great if you can help me with a code

Comment: Other factors to consider: 1) backup the files 2) do any of the files contain vba code that will run on open, or trigger events on change 3) do any of the files contain more than one sheet 4) do any of the words to find appear more than once in a file 5) do any of the files contain formulas and do you want to replace in those 6) do you want to replace partial matches, or whole cells only 7) do any of the replace words appear elsewhere in the find list

Answer (score -1):

1.Add the below code into the VBA project of your Reference file.
2.Replace "C:\YourFolder\" with your folder Path where you store 1000 Excel files. Don't keep non-Excel files there.
3.Assuming your Reference file structure is like the below, you can run the macro. It might take a while depending on the number of files in the folder.
[image: file structure]

```
Sub LoopAndReplace()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim masterFile As String
masterFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim lastRowMaster As Long
lastRowMaster = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Dim myFolder As String
myFolder = "C:\YourFolder\"
Dim myFile As String
myFile = Dir(myFolder)


While myFile <> ""
    If masterFile <> myFile Then
        Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFolder & myFile)
        For i = 2 To lastRowMaster
            Cells.Replace What:=Workbooks(masterFile).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, _
            Replacement:=Workbooks(masterFile).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Next i
        myWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    End If
    myFile = Dir
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Should my reference excel sheet be in the same folder or can it be in different folder and where should i mention my reference file sheet path and name

Comment: As I mentioned: 1.Add the below code into the VBA project of your Reference file, so there is no need to reference the name of the file anywhere. This File can be in the same of different folder.